# Scheduling Apex class twice a day

Tags: scheduled-apex

I want to schedule my apex class to run twice a day, i.e
8 AM and 8 PM
How this can be achieved?
What will be the desired cron expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
String sch = '0 0 11/12 * * ?';
//0 0 {time to schedule}/{hours until repeat} * * ?
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
String cron = '0 00 08,20 * * ?';
```

Runs at 0800h and at 2000h every day